# Django with Oracle showing wrong date in template

Tags: django, oracle, django-templates

I have an issue that has only arisen as I'm moving to the Oracle backend from sqlite.  In my templates, I'm using the built in `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT` filter.  Using sqlite, the date shows correctly, (e.g. 9/21/2012).  Moving to Oracle as the backend, the date is showing the day before the date in the database, always (e.g., 9/20/2012).  The Oracle data shows 21-SEP-12 12.00.00.000000 AM as the value in the database.  My template displays the data like so:

```
    <td>{{ ec.effective_date|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }}</td>
```

I'm running this against Oracle 11.  Is this a Django bug?  If so, how do I report it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else runs into this issue, it's happening because I was using DateTimeField model fields.  In Oracle, that translates to a timestamp, and I guess Django converts that to the previous day.  Changing my model fields to DateField, syncdb, and everything is now showing the correct date, and Oracle is using a Date column type, not timestamp.